# simplify js code: get range between two numbers as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, simplify

can the the following code be simplified?

```
let arr = []
for (let value = startRange.value; value <= endRange.value; value++) {
  arr.push({value: value, someothervalue: value*2})
}
return arr
```

So for example something like:

```
Array.range(3,6)
```

and the output would be

```
[
  {value: 3, someothervalue: 6},
  {value: 4, someothervalue: 8},
  {value: 5, someothervalue: 10},
  {value: 6, someothervalue: 12}
]
```

FYI: the `someothervalue`should just demonstrate that the object has multiple values relying on each range value.

Comment: The "FYI" that you have mentioned, what output is expected, can you give an example? The code that you written is very simple for me.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the Mozilla Docs for [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), you can generate a range with a function like this:

```js
const range = (start, stop, step = 1) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
console.log(range(3, 6));
```

You can then tack an [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the end to get your `someOtherValue`.

```js
const range = (start, stop, step = 1) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
const output = range(3, 6).map(i => ({ value: i, otherval: i * 2 }));
console.log(output);
```

Alternatively, you can just modify the `range` method if you won't be using it for anything else:

```js
let range = (start, stop, step = 1) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => ({ value: start + (i * step), other: (start + (i * step)) * 2 }));

console.log(range(3, 6));

// Expanded for readability:

range = (start, stop, step = 1) => {
  return Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1 }, (_, i) => {
    const val = start + (i * step);
    return {
      value: val,
      other1: val * 2,
      other2: val * 3
      // And so on
    }
  });
}

console.log(range(6, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const range = (start, stop, {value, othervalue, stepUp}) => Array.from({length: (stop - start) + 1}, (v, i) => ({[value]: start + i, [othervalue]: (start + i) * stepUp}));

let result = range(3, 6, {'value': 'myvalue', 'othervalue': 'myothervalue', 'stepUp': 2 });
let result2 = range(4, 8, {'value': 'myvalue1', 'othervalue': 'myothervalue1', 'stepUp': 2 });

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

You can use `Array.from` method to generate the sequence, you can configure the  key name also by passing as an argument, value: 'set your value key name', othervalue: 'set your other value key name' also pass stepup value

Answer (score -1):

Well you could remove the '=' in the loop cause most people wouldn't expect the larger value to be inclusive :P

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: This answer would be better suited as a comment on the post; it does not attempt to fix the problem OP is asking.